# CSS Drop Down Menu Hover Not Showing in IE 7

Tags: drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, hover

I've been staring at my codes for hours and can't seem to figure out why my drop down hover menu isn't showing up at all in IE 7. When I hover the menu, the drop down doesn't show up at all. It works fine in firefox, chrome, safari and IE 8. I basically thought myself everything I know so I am a total newbie. I've searched around and read something about adding some javascript but that doesn't seem to work...unless I may have overlook certain errors or missed something- but any help would be greatly appreciated....pretty please 0:) and thanks in advance!

Here's the CSS:

```
#navmenu {
height:50px;
position:relative;
width:950px;
z-index:1;
top:-142px;
margin:0;}

#navmenu ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
line-height:50px;
position:relative;
float:left;}

#navmenu li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
position: relative;}

#navmenu ul li a {
height:50px;
width:auto;
    display:block;
padding:0 20px 0 21px;}

#navmenu ul ul {
position:absolute;
visibility:hidden;
top:50px;
z-index:1;}

 #navmenu ul li:hover ul, #navmenu ul li.sfhover: {
visibility:visible;
z-index:9999; 
display:block;}
```

and for the javascript I found that I put in the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sfHover = function() {
var sfEls = document.getElementById("navmenu").getElementsByTagName("LI");
for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
    sfEls[i].onmouseover=function() {
        this.className+=" sfhover";
    }
    sfEls[i].onmouseout=function() {
        this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"),     "");
    }
}
}
    if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", sfHover);
    </script>
```

Comment: `#navmenu ul li:hover ul, #navmenu ul li.sfhover:` should that trailing colon be there? Also can you create a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a "zoom : 1" to your ul-element. This mostly fix similiar problems in IE.

Comment: What you can do is creating a pure CSS based menu without JavaScript. See this tutorial: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/ hope that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! But I believe my current menu is already pure CSS based and I only added the JavaScript to fix IE 7 bug hoping that would solve the issue...but it doesn't so I'm still pretty stumped...:/

Comment: nevermind! i managed to find out the issue... which was some gradient background color codes that collided with the drop down..odd.